# How access in ruby a JSON attribute within inline string variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, syntax, inline

Is it possible to do smth. like this:

```
puts "DEBUG: #{@search_params[0]["param"]}"
puts "DEBUG: #{@search_params[0][\"param\"]}"
puts "DEBUG: #{@search_params[0]['param']}"
puts 'DEBUG: #{@search_params[0]['param']}'
```

where

```
@search_params = [{param: "abc"}, {param: "def"}]
```

but in that way, that `@search_params[0]["param"]` will be substituted to a JSON argument `param` in a JSON document `@search_params`?

P.S. `puts "DEBUG: #{@search_params[0].param}"` and `puts "DEBUG: #{@search_params[0][:param]}"` do not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use like below :

```
@search_params = [{param: "abc"},{param: "def"}]
puts "DEBUG: #{@search_params[0][:param]}"
# >> DEBUG: abc
```

You have symbol key `:param`,not the string.

Comment: is it possible to define so: `@search_params = [{"param": "abc"}, {"param": "def"}]`?

Comment: @static **NO**.Type the same in your IRB,you will get the answer.. :)

Comment: @static see the fourth paragraph here - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html